# td:contains is creating a new row instead of replacing the value in the cell

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to replace a table td cell with a count of values in the column; however, the value is being displayed in a new row instead of in the cell.

The html is:

```
                                 <tr>
                                    <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>Joeys</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY1T1</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY1T2</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY1T3</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY1T4</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY2T1</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY2T2</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY2T3</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY2T4</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY3T1</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY3T2</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY3T3</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY3T4</td>
                                </tr>
```

The jQuery is:

```
    var countJY1T1 = cubPackDetailsTable
    .cells( null, 8 )
    .render( 'display' )
    .filter( function ( value, index ) {
        return value == "J" ? true : false;
    } ).count();
    $("#cubPackDetailsTable td:contains('JY1T1')").html(countJY1T1);
```

The page displayed is:

[image]

The "5" should replace the "JY1T1", not be in a new row.

I use:

```
var today = new Date();
var y1 = today.getFullYear();
$("#cubPackDetailsTable td:contains('YEAR1')").html("<b>"+y1+"</b>");
```

To get the "2020" at the top of the page and that, as you see, works.

The full table(as requested by jwatts1980):

```
                       <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="cubPackDetailsTable">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center">YEAR1</td>
                                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center">YEAR2</td>
                                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center">YEAR3</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>Joeys</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY1T1</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY1T2</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY1T3</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY1T4</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY2T1</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY2T2</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY2T3</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY2T4</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY3T1</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY3T2</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY3T3</td>
                                    <td style="text-align:center">JY3T4</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Number</th>
                                    <th>First Name</th>
                                    <th>Surname</th>
                                    <th>Invested</th>
                                    <th>Current Section</th>
                                    <th>DOB</th>
                                    <th>Gender</th>
                                    <th>Current Age</th>
                                    <th>T1</th>
                                    <th>T2</th>
                                    <th>T3</th>
                                    <th>T4</th>
                                    <th>T1</th>
                                    <th>T2</th>
                                    <th>T3</th>
                                    <th>T4</th>
                                    <th>T1</th>
                                    <th>T2</th>
                                    <th>T3</th>
                                    <th>T4</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="cubPackDetailsTablebody">
                            </tbody>

                        </table>
```

DataTables jQuery (for Tim):

```
if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#cubPackDetailsTable' ) ) {
    var cubPackDetailsTable = $('#cubPackDetailsTable').DataTable();
}
else {
    var cubPackDetailsTable = $('#cubPackDetailsTable').DataTable( {
```

Comment: I think we need to see more of your HTML to know for sure. Right now, the only thing jumping out to me is that `countJY1T1` is an `int`, and `html()` expects a `string`, and so there might be some Javascript typing weirdness going on. Maybe try `.html(countJY1T1+'')`

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution and it did not work as required. I have included the html for the table. Kind regards, Glyn.

Comment: What is `cubPackDetailsTable` in your jQuery code? Are you using any jQuery plugins like datatables?

Comment: Hi Tim, Yes, I am using DataTables. I have added the code to my post.

Comment: what if you do .empty().html(countJY1T1) ?

Comment: Hi vbotio, this did not work.

Comment: I have done further testing using "$("#cubPackDetailsTable td:contains('JY1T1')").html("9");". It works before the DataTables is loaded (i.e., before the "for Tim" code; however, not after. For instance I added another "$(document).ready(function(){" with "$("#cubPackDetailsTable td:contains('JY1T1')").html("9");" and it did not work (i.e., it is after the DataTables load). So is there a way to do this (tally the values in the column and then display the values)?

Answer (score 0):

Change each td to contain an id, e.g.,

```
<td id="JY1T1" style="text-align:center">JY1T1</td>
```

or

```
<td id="JY1T1" style="text-align:center"></td>
```

And then use the following to populate:

```
('#JY1T1').html(countJY1T1);
```